# how to update the version of Xcode that pods works with?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode14

After I updated my Xcode to 14 version is get broken.
I guess, it because version of Xcode at pod is different:

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.11.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.9p207 (2021-11-24 revision 67954) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 13.0 (22A5286j)
       Xcode : 13.4.1 (13F100) // here
         Git : git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

how to update there version to 14?

[image]

Comment: The real issue is `Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib`. If you see the System Ruby mentioned, you're doing it wrong. You must install your own Ruby and use it for cocoapods and all other gems.